# Kill single activity Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm an Android newbie. I'm writing an app to trace the Activity lifecycle using Log statements. I want to kill my app in order to see the onDestroy() event being called. I've added a button that calls finish to do this, but I've not been able to terminate the app. I've also tried System.exit(0), but my app won't terminate. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_DISPLAY = "DEBUG";  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onCreate called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onPause called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onResume called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onStop called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onStart called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onRestart called");
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: what log it showing!??? you have not override onDestroy method in you code

Comment: your `addListenerOnButton()` method is never called. Call in in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must override `onDestroy` in order to check if it is called, and call your `addListenerOnButton` method too:

Try with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_DISPLAY = "DEBUG";  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onCreate called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onDestroy called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onPause called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onResume called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onStop called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onStart called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onRestart called");
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First add missing `onDestroy` implementation to show you logs :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(LOG_DISPLAY, "onDestroy called");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Then simply open activity and exit it with hardware `back` button. You will see `onDestroy` logs.

You will have same effect calling `finish()` programmatically as well, just dont forget to place call to your `addListenerOnButton` somewhere within `onCreate`